# Bootstrap 4 Flex Box Grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4, bootstrap-4

According to [this post](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/whats-new-in-bootstrap-4), Bootstrap 4 offers an opt-in flex box grid.

> There’s a boolean variable in the _variables.scss file called
>   $enable-flex. If you set this to true and recompile, a ton of things
>   happen.

Q: How do you recompile Bootstrap? I typed:

```
git clone https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap
```

on the command line and my windows computer just hung. I finally had to Ctrl+C and exit.

Comment: See http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/build-tools/ . Summary: (1) Install Node.js (2) `npm install` in the bootstrap directory (3) `grunt dist`

Comment: If you download bootstrap, it contains bootstrap-flex.css that is created with flex enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [scotch.io](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/whats-new-in-bootstrap-4) has a flex box compiled version.

Answer (score 2):

To compile scss files you need SASS compiler:
http://sass-lang.com/

You can find versions for linux and windows.

Answer (score 2):

Import `bootstrap-flex` into your SASS compiler which also sets `$enable-flex:true`

[Demo here](http://www.codeply.com/go/YFFFWHVoRB)

***UPDATE:***
As of Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6, flexbox is now the default.
http://www.codeply.com/go/p/bootstrap_4.0.alpha.6
http://www.codeply.com/go/p/bootstrap_4.0.0